# using grepl in R with ddply and transform

Tags: r, transform, plyr, grepl

Quick question regarding syntax I think. I have a df as laid out below. I want to identify the first time a person gets an apple, kiwi or orange. I do this by creating three new variables called 'apple1', 'kiwi1' and 'orange1' using the following code:

```
ddply(z, "noms", transform, 
  apple1 = as.numeric(!duplicated(fruits) & fruits == "apple"))->z
```

However, I actually want to use grepl to identify my fruit instead but can't manage to get the code to work out. This is what I have tried:

```
ddply(z, "noms", transform, 
   apple20 = as.numeric(!duplicated(fruits) & z[grep('^app.*?', z$fruits),]))->z

ddply(z, "noms", transform, 
   apple20 = as.numeric(!duplicated(fruits) & grep('^app.*?', z$fruits)))->z
```

If anyone could point me to where I'm going wrong here that would be great. Thank you!

Sample DF

```
 noms fruits kiwi1 orange1 apple1
1  john banana     0       0      0
2  john  apple     0       0      1
3  john  apple     0       0      0
4  john  apple     0       0      0
5  lucy   kiwi     1       0      0
6  lucy orange     0       1      0
7  lucy  apple     0       0      1
8  lucy  berry     0       0      0
9  mary  apple     0       0      1
10 mary  grape     0       0      0
11 mary orange     0       1      0
12 mary  apple     0       0      0
13  tom orange     0       1      0
```

Comment: you have `grep` (which returns a vector of integers) instead of `grepl` (which returns a vector of TRUE / FALSE values).   Similarly, you are using  `& z[..]`, which is likely to give you unintended results, especially if `z` cannot be coerced into a TRUE/FALSE value.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta thanks for th info - but I've changed grep to grepl and I am still getting the same errors "Error in data.frame(list(noms = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), fruits = c(2L, 1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 30". z is the name of the df

Comment: the error is telling you that you are trying to combine two boolean vectors of different lengths

Comment: Figured it out! i switched to using a data.table as my df had >1million rows. so here is how I did it - z<-z[,apple20 := grepl('app.*?', fruits), by='noms']

Comment: there you go!  Are you sure about your logic though?  I dont think the `by` is accomplishing anything here (results wise)

Comment: ha! My logic is questionable 97% percent of the time @RicardoSaporta!! It did what I wanted it to do, in my real data, so happy enough with that. Thanks for the push towards working it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
z<-z[,apple20 := grepl('app.*?', fruits), by='noms']
```